# Unexpected failure in PHP / Laravel Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a query I am running using Laravel, which runs absolutely fine on my development host, however I get an error when I deploy it to my UAT host.  I have simplified all examples to make it easier to work out what is going on.

The simplified code:

```
DB::select("SELECT c.* 
            FROM (SELECT 0 AS xxx, u.* FROM users u) c
            ORDER  BY c.xxx DESC");
```

The error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'c.xxx' in 'order clause' (SQL: SELECT c.* 
>   FROM (SELECT 0 AS xxx, u.* FROM users u) c
>   ORDER BY c.xxx DESC)

When I run the following query in Workbench directly, it works absolutely fine:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM   (SELECT 0 AS xxx, 
               u.* 
        FROM   users u) c 
ORDER  BY c.xxx DESC
```

So in short, it works on dev DB directly, works within dev code, works on UAT DB directly but fails on UAT application.

Any ideas why the database query could possibly behave differently to the query run via Laravel / php?  Any idea why one machine would behave fine and there other display the above error?

Comment: DB::raw("SELECT c.* 
            FROM (SELECT 0 AS xxx, u.* FROM users u) c
            ORDER  BY c.xxx DESC"); try this ?

Comment: Did you use migrations for the database?

Comment: Did you tried setting xxx between SQL quotes ``, like : SELECT 0 AS \`xxx\`

Comment: why do you want to order by a fixed-value column?? All the rows will have the same value anyway.

Comment: The above is for demo purposes.  I have simplified the problem as much as I could, in the final code this will not be a fixed value.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have an invisible character or a character that looks very similar to a letter used in the name of the field or in the order by clause. This character throws off the parser, but it is difficult to spot with naked eyes.

Comment: @Shadow - I very much thought the same thing initially.  I have rewritten it a ton of times.  In fact this all started as an eloquent query with only the "0 AS xxx" as a raw part of the query.

Comment: @AnarBayramov - strangely, your query returned "SELECT c.* FROM (SELECT 0 AS xxx, u.* FROM users u) c ORDER BY c.xxx DESC" - looks like this method doesnt execute the query?

Comment: @csblo - yes - I tried that, same result sadly.